# CLion warning with string literals in C++17

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14, c++17, clion

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour in CLion. I have two functions that takes as a parameter a `std::string` and a `const std::string&`. I call them passing a string literal.

I have tried with different versions of C++: C++17 and C++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print(std::string str){
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
}

void print_ref(const std::string& str){
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
}



int main() {
    print("Hello World!");
    print_ref("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

If the code is  C++17, ​CLion (or better IntelliSense) reports this warning `Paramemeter type mismatch: Types 'std::string' and 'const char[13]' are not compatible`, but if I switch to C++14 the warning disappears. Is the code correct?

Comment: Is it a compiler warning (i.e. shown after you build your code) or IntelliSense-*whatever-it's-called-there* warning (shown when you hover mouse over the code)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need `#include <string>`

Comment: @NeilButterworth it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @eerorika Sorry, my fault. Understand if the code was correct or not.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen it's an IntelliSense warning

Comment: @neil [No repro for either case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa4828cf3c13ebfd)

Comment: With that include added this is a perfectly good C++11 program, and I don't believe the later standards have invalidated that. So it looks like a CLion issue.

Comment: @RiccardoMereu _"it's an IntelliSense warning"_ Phew!

Comment: @RiccardoMereu the shown code is correct. Nothing wrong with it regardless of standard version.

Comment: @πάντα   That's dependent on your compiler/library version - if you want to reliably use `std::string` you need to `#include <string>`

Comment: @Neil I of course know that. _"So it looks like a CLion issue."_ I'd suspect the CLion devs call it _"a feature"_ :)

Comment: @NeilButterworth @eeroika @πάντα thanks. I've added ```#include <string>```, but the IntelliSense's warning is still there, then I think that is simply a CLion issue.

Comment: @RiccardoMereu Intellisense needs to be fast as can be not to come into the user's way while typing. Thus these kind of things are often a little bit dumber than the actuall compiler that's used when building. Thus these kind of false negatives provided by intellisense are quite usual with most IDE's.

Comment: I've just updated CLion and the warning has disappeared. Thanks all!

Comment: I am using the newest version of CLion and exactly the same error is still there. I included <string> but not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with CLions code completion / lint feature. Somehow the linter doesn't realize that while `const char[]` and `std::string` aren't the same types, `std::string` has a perfectly valid implicit constructor which makes this code work just fine.

I wouldn't mind these kind of quirks too much. As a general rule of thumb if you're unsure if a warning/error generated by these types of linters is valid then just try building your project, if the actual compilation process produces an error only then your code is somehow wrong.

Comment: your ID/Profile Picture is fantastic

Comment: @Ric _@Sombrero_ is fantastic :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue in your env. Works just fine in my case.

[image]

**Sys config**

CLion

```
Version 2019.1.3 (CL-191.7141.37)
```

LLVM

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
```

Comment: As said by @Yksisarvinen, can you please me share what is your CLion version?

Comment: @RiccardoMereu good point!

Comment: I've just updated CLion and the warning has disappeared